# Set images on Pdf using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, wcf, itext, wcf-data-services

I am working on WCF service to create a pad file and want to set image on created pdf.
 Below is my code. it gives me error "object reference not set to an object instance"

```
 string str = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("App_Data/suc.png");
 Image imgCheckBoxChecked = Image.GetInstance(str);
```

The other thing I try and it gives me error :Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\suc.png: Below is my other code

```
  Image imgCheckBoxChecked = Image.GetInstance("App_Data/suc.png");

  cell.AddElement(imgCheckBoxChecked);
  cell.Colspan = 4;
  table.AddCell(cell);
```

Any idea on how to solve this error and set image on pdf.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AppDomain.BaseDirectory` to get directory to the main dll, after this you can use it to get the path to your image dll, like `Path.Combine(AppDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data\\suc.png")`, if you host service in ASP.NET, and the dll is in `Bin` directory you can use relative path like `Path.Combine(AppDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\App_Data\\suc.png")`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it gives me error : "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.AppDomain.BaseDirectory.get'"

Comment: `BaseDirectory` is a property for `AppDomain` class, to get current `AppDomain` you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`, so final code will be `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

```
string pdfPath = "~/PDF/File_1.pdf";
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image.JPG"));
img.ScalePercent(100f);
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath(pdfPath), FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph(sb.ToString()));
doc.Add(img);
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. As I am working on WCF services My code is in a class file and I do not find server.mappath.and I also try string str = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("App_Data/suc.png"); but it not wroking.